# Why is LLVM segfaulting when I try to emit object code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to follow along with the LLVM tutorial on compiler implementation, but my code segfaults when I try to emit object code.

Here's a minimal example that attempts to compile a function `func`. To keep things simple, `func` is a function that does nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <llvm/ADT/Optional.h>
#include <llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h>
#include <llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Type.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Verifier.h>
#include <llvm/Support/CodeGen.h>
#include <llvm/Support/FileSystem.h>
#include <llvm/Support/Host.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/Target/TargetMachine.h>
#include <llvm/Target/TargetOptions.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context);
    llvm::Module      module("module", context);

    llvm::Function* const func = llvm::Function::Create(
        llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type::getVoidTy(context),
                                std::vector<llvm::Type*>(), false),
        llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "func", &module
    );

    builder.SetInsertPoint(llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "entry", func));

    llvm::verifyFunction(*func);

    func->dump();

    llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargets();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs();
    llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers();
    llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters();

    const std::string triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();

    std::string message;
    const llvm::Target* const target = llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(
        triple, message
    );
    if (!target) throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't find target.");

    llvm::TargetMachine* const machine = target->createTargetMachine(
        triple, "generic", "", llvm::TargetOptions(),
        llvm::Optional<llvm::Reloc::Model>()
    );

    module.setDataLayout(machine->createDataLayout());
    module.setTargetTriple(triple);

    std::error_code code;
    llvm::raw_fd_ostream obj_file("func.o", code, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
    if (code) throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't open object file.");

    llvm::legacy::PassManager manager;
    if (
        machine->addPassesToEmitFile(manager, obj_file,
                                     llvm::TargetMachine::CGFT_ObjectFile)
    ) throw std::runtime_error("Adding passes failed.");

    std::cout << "Running pass manager." << std::endl;
    manager.run(module);
    std::cout << "Ran pass manager." << std::endl;

    obj_file.flush();

}
```

Here's the command I'm compiling with. I'm using GCC version 6.3.1 and LLVM version 3.9.1.

```
g++ src/main.cc -o bin/test -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra             \
    -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-parameter \
    -Werror -ggdb -O0 `llvm-config --system-libs --libs core`
```

And here's the output.

```
define void @func() {
entry:
}

Running pass manager.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The translation to IR succeeds--at least to me the dump looks correct--but the segfault occurs on calling `llvm::legacy::PassManager::run`.

I tried stepping through the code with GDB. Here's the backtrace from the moment of the segfault.

```
#0  0x00007ffff56ce72f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libLLVM-3.9.so
#1  0x00007ffff56477c2 in llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) () from /usr/lib/libLLVM-3.9.so
#2  0x00007ffff5647b4b in llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) () from /usr/lib/libLLVM-3.9.so
#3  0x00007ffff5647e74 in llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) () from /usr/lib/libLLVM-3.9.so
#4  0x0000000000403ab6 in main () at src/main.cc:76
```

Unfortunately, my LLVM installation (installed using `pacman` on Arch Linux) doesn't seem to have line-number debugging information, so I can't tell exactly where in `llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction`'s execution the problem is occurring.

Is there anything obviously wrong, either in concept or in implementation, with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All LLVM basic blocks must be terminated (see e.g. http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#details). In your case, the generated IR should look like this:

```
define void @func() {
entry:
    ret void
}
```

In your C++ code, you need to add `builder.CreateRetVoid()` before you call `llvm::verifyFunction`.

Also, `llvm::verifyFunction` is not visibly outputting an error because you haven't passed the second parameter which indicates the stream to which LLVM should output errors. Try this instead to output to stderr:

```
llvm::verifyFunction(*func, &llvm::errs())
```

You also should check the return value of `llvm::verifyFunction`. A `true` return value indicates an error.

See: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a26389c546573f058ad8ecbdc5c1933cf and http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/raw__ostream_8h.html

You should also consider verifying the entire module before generating object files by calling `llvm::verifyModule(theModule, theOsStream)` (see http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Verifier_8h.html).

Finally, I'd recommend inspecting the IR generated by Clang when compiling C code so that you can inspect what correctly generated IR looks like. For example, you can create a simple C file as follows:

```
// test.c
void func(void) {}
```

And then compile and view as follows:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm test.c
cat test.ll
```

[giving](https://godbolt.org/z/yT-VWt):

```
define dso_local void @_Z4funcv() #0 !dbg !7 {
  ret void, !dbg !11
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "frame-pointer"="all" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks! I shouldn't have assumed that no `return` statement was necessary just because the function was `void`. Whoops. The other tips are helpful too.